# AttributeError on Oandapy API

Tags: python-3.7, attributeerror

I'm trying to do "100 lines of python code" for algorithmic trading and have been stopped early in my tracks with an attribute error.

I'm using sublime text and running it on python 3.7.

Here is the code I used:

```
import configparser
import oandapy as opy

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("oanda.cfg")

oanda = opy.API(environment = "practice",
                         access_token = config["oanda"] ["access_token"] )
```

Here are the results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "100lines.py", line 7, in <module>
oanda = opy.API(environment = "practice",
AttributeError: module 'oandapy' has no attribute 'API'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
# Print all attributes/functions in module
print(dir(opy))
```

and check the modules present

I think you'll have to use 'APIv20' rather than just 'API'

Answer (score 2):

The api method is now called `APIv20` in the current version (0.0.9).

so changing the last line to:

```
oanda = opy.APIv20(environment='practice', access_token=config['oanda']['access_token'])
```

will make solve your issue.